# Django/CKEditor/Javascript Issue including text in textarea

Tags: javascript, django, django-ckeditor

I'm working on a forum with Django that allows users to reply to each other (and quotes the original user). This works perfectly when I do a first reply (I'm using a one line javascript that updates the textarea via grabbing the id and updating the innerHTML with a django template from my view, see html template below) :

[image]

[image]

Issue is, when I attempt to quote an already quoted message, nothing appears in the textarea field. Below are my views and templates:

**View**

```
@login_required
def reply_to_post(request, pk, topic_id, post_pk):
reply = get_object_or_404(Post, topic_id=topic_id, pk=post_pk)
topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, board__pk=pk, pk=topic_id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.post = reply
        post.created_by = request.user
        post.topic = topic
        user = reply.created_by
        title = post.topic
        post.save()
        
        reply.last_update = timezone.now()
        reply.save()
        notify.send(request.user, recipient=user, actor=request.user, verb='replied to your post', target=title, nf_type='replied_by_one_user')
        reverse('home')
        
        topic_url = reverse('topic_posts', kwargs={'pk': pk, 'topic_pk': topic_id})
        topic_post_url = '{url}?page={page}#{id}'.format(
            url = topic_url,
            id=post.pk,
            page=topic.get_page_count()
        )
        return redirect(topic_post_url)
else:
    form = PostForm
    
return render(request, 'reply_post.html', {'topic': topic, 'form': form, 'reply': reply})
```

**reply_form.html**

```
{% load form_tags widget_tweaks %}
{% load static %}
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <p {% if forloop.last %} class="mb-0"{% endif %}>{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}

{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group">

    {{ field.label_tag }}

    {% render_field field class=field|input_class %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ error }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    {% if field.help_text %}
        <small class="form-text text-muted">
            {{ field.help_text|safe }}
        </small>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}

{% block extrahead %}
<script>
document.getElementById("id_message").innerHTML = "<blockquote><i><b>{{ reply.created_by }} 
wrote:</b><br />{{ reply.message|safe }}</i></blockquote>";
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

**reply_post.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title %}Post a reply{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheet %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/simplemde.min.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}
{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb %}
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Boards</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'board_topics' topic.board.pk %}">{{ topic.board.name }}</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'topic_posts'  topic.board.pk topic.pk %}">{{ topic.subject }}</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Post a reply</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.media }}
        {% include 'includes/reply_form.html' %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Post a reply</button>
        {{ reply.message|safe }}
    </form>
    <div style="height: 200px; overflow: scroll;">
    {% for post in topic.get_last_ten_posts %}
        <div class="card mb-2">
            <div class="card-body p-3">
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <strong class="text-muted">{{ post.created_by.username }}</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 text-right">
                        <small class="text-muted">{{ post.created_at }}</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{ post.get_messages_as_markdown }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Oddly I can render this content outside of the textarea (see reply_post.html):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue, with javascript you need to encapsulate the string with ` symbols, so the javascript line is:

```
document.getElementById("id_message").innerHTML = `<blockquote><i><b>{{ reply.created_by }} 
wrote:</b><br />{{ reply.message|safe }}</i></blockquote>`
```

The joys of coding, a few characters was the issue!